# Synergy prevents click and drag actions in some Windows applications

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, mouse, synergy, imac

My Synergy setup is a Windows 7 x64 server and an iMac client.

The problem I'm experiencing is that Synergy prevents click and drag actions in 'some' Windows applications.

I notice it most often in Photoshop - while Synergy server is running I am unable to apply a mask or use any paint or rubber tool for more than a single click.

The problem also occurs to a lesser extent in other programs, i.e. in MS Word I am sometimes unable to highlight text using the mouse - no problem if using the keyboard though, and since I mostly use the keyboard it doesn't bother me so much, however rearranging the text with a mouse is difficult.

Understandably its somewhat irritating to have to quit Synergy - which otherwise works perfectly - just to apply a mask or rearrange some text.

The problem goes away the moment I close Synergy server and comes back when I start it up again.

Anyone have any ideas how that might be fixed or is it a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a bug, and is normally caused by "stuck keys" (when Synergy is mistakenly telling the OS a key is being pressed when it isn't.)  Usually having the Escape key stuck prevents dragging and dropping.  Workarounds for this are varied, but for me (with a Windows client and Linux server) pressing all the modifier keys one by one while on the client screen (alt, shift, ctrl, win), the escape key, and also pressing alt+ctrl+pause (to bring up the Windows alt+ctrl+del screen) and escape fixes the problem (until the Windows PC is next locked with Win+L or by the screensaver.)

Comment: ok, that sort of makes sense - so to get around the problem you press alt then shift then ctrl then win then esc and alt-ctrl-pause - i had noticed the shift key getting stuck and that pressing it once or twice fixed it, didn't think of another key being stuck - if it works i'll be back to accept your answer

Comment: Is this the bug: https://github.com/synergy/synergy/issues/3784?

Answer (score 1):

I use Synergy for two Win 10 clients and MS Word and Outlook often suffer with this problem.  I have found that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> clears the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the click and drag issue, but I had the same problem with selecting (highlighting) text with shift+arrow keys.  Based on the information [here](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/issues/detail?id=392#c5) indicating that only the right shift key is affected (which is, in fact, the case), I was able to work around it by remapping the right shift key to the left shift key with this AutoHotKey script:

```
#SingleInstance force
#NoTrayIcon
RShift::LShift
```

I went ahead and compiled it to an executable and put it in my startup directory.